# Interaction - IInteractionRequestAware properties not populating

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm trying to create a custom popup in it's own module which leads me to the following situation (`ContentControl` inside `PopupWindowAction`):

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding Path=MyRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MyRegion}"/>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The view is loaded into the popup window nicely but the **IInteractionRequestAware** properties (**Notification** and **FinishInteraction**) are null on both the View and View Model.

Here's the Prism source code that sets these properties:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the WindowContent or its DataContext implements <see cref="IInteractionRequestAware"/>.
    /// If so, it sets the corresponding value.
    /// Also, if WindowContent does not have a RegionManager attached, it creates a new scoped RegionManager for it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notification">The notification to be set as a DataContext in the HostWindow.</param>
    /// <param name="wrapperWindow">The HostWindow</param>
    protected virtual void PrepareContentForWindow(INotification notification, Window wrapperWindow)
    {
        if (this.WindowContent == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // We set the WindowContent as the content of the window. 
        wrapperWindow.Content = this.WindowContent;

        Action<IInteractionRequestAware> setNotificationAndClose = (iira) =>
        {
            iira.Notification = notification;
            iira.FinishInteraction = () => wrapperWindow.Close();
        };

        MvvmHelpers.ViewAndViewModelAction(this.WindowContent, setNotificationAndClose);
    }
```

Does this mean that the `ContentControl` object is being checked to see if it implements `IInteractionRequestAware` and not my View or View Model?

Is it possible to use the Region Manager to specify a custom popup view with all the injection taking place and still have the `IInteractionRequestAware` properties set as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options; create a custom ContentControl that implements the proper interface.  Or, create and use a dialog service instead.  I would actually recommend using a dialog service instead since you want to have a more dynamic popup behavior. Dialog Service is covered in the PluralSight course 'Prism Problems & Solutions: Showing Multiple Shells'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I was doing something similar and came up to the same problem. I addressed it by subclassing PopupWindowAction. I'm putting this here as a 3rd option for anyone interested.